# How to track down the cause a SIGSEGV error in an ML Engine training job?

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a custom tensorflow estimator on ML engine and running into this error:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 11(SIGSEGV)
```

with the only other error log being:

```
Command '['python3', '-m', 'train_model.train', ... ']' returned non-zero exit status -11
```

There is no longer traceback so this 'invalid memory reference or segmentation fault [code](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/status-codes)' is all I have to go on.

This SIGSEGV error does not always occur. Some training jobs run without problems, others throw this error after 4 hours, and others after 15 minutes.

I've varied parts of the estimator training code to try to trial and error my way to finding the cause but have had no success.

I thought the `11` code may correspond to [this error code](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto#L157) in the google apis and found a [number of people have experienced](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19541) `OutOfSequence` and `OutOfRange` errors when using custom metrics in the estimator `EvalSpec` but I do not think that is what is causing the error here as I use a `tf.metric`.

I am using the `BASIC` scale tier and looking at the CPU utilisation it never goes above 80% and the memory utilisation graph shows around 25%.

I am caching the tensorflow dataset, but I also receive this error when not caching the dataset. The error occurs when running the `train_and_evaluate` method as well as the `train` method.

Is there any advice as to how I can track down the route cause of this crash in the training jobs? Or what some of the common causes of this crash are? Is the solution just to use a larger memory machine?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: nope. When using larger compute instances the error happened less often but it still occurred.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the dataset and model?

Comment: I understand it's been a few years, but I've encountered the same error and I was wondering if you were able to solve the issue

Comment: I'm not still working on it. But I never did find out the cause of the problem